# How to make Selenium not wait till full page load, which has a slow script?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, pageloadstrategy

Selenium `driver.get (url)` wait till full page load. But a scraping page try to load some dead JS script. So my Python script wait for it and doesn't works few minutes. This problem can be on every pages of a site.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.cortinadecor.com/productos/17/estores-enrollables-screen/estores-screen-corti-3000')
# It try load: https://www.cetelem.es/eCommerceCalculadora/resources/js/eCalculadoraCetelemCombo.js 
driver.find_element_by_name('ANCHO').send_keys("100")
```

How to limit the time wait, block AJAX load of a file, or is other way?

Also I test my script in `webdriver.Chrome()`, but will use PhantomJS(), or probably Firefox(). So, if some method uses a change in browser settings, then it must be universal.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

When Selenium loads a page/url by default it follows a default configuration with `pageLoadStrategy` set to `normal`. To make Selenium not to wait for full page load we can configure the `pageLoadStrategy`. `pageLoadStrategy` supports 3 different values as follows:

1. **`normal`** (full page load)
2. **`eager`** (interactive)
3. **`none`**

Here is the code block to configure the **`pageLoadStrategy`** :

- ***Firefox*** :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

  caps = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
  caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "normal"  #  complete
  #caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "eager"  #  interactive
  #caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(desired_capabilities=caps, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://google.com")
  ```
- ***Chrome*** :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

  caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
  caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "normal"  #  complete
  #caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "eager"  #  interactive
  #caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://google.com")
  ```

> **Note** : `pageLoadStrategy` values **`normal`**, **`eager`** and **`none`** is a requirement as per [**WebDriver W3C Editor's Draft**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#navigation) but `pageLoadStrategy` value as **`eager`** is still a *WIP (Work In Progress)* within **ChromeDriver** implementation. You can find a detailed discussion in [“Eager” Page Load Strategy workaround for Chromedriver Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087832/eager-page-load-strategy-workaround-for-chromedriver-selenium-in-python)

Comment: It works in Firefox(). In Chrome() the "eager" option throws an error "unsupported". Run follows:

    caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
    caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps)
    driver.get('https://href...')
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_name('ANCHO').send_keys("100")

Comment: @bl79 Yes :) I know. What I suggested is from WebDriver's W3C recommendation. ChromeDriver will follow the suit soon. Thanks

Comment: Instead of `time.sleep`, better to use `driver.implicitly_wait`

Comment: Chrome still hasn't followed suit and it doesn't seem like they will

Comment: @TimWachter Checkout my answer update and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @DebanjanB though `caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"` gives back the control over driver in chrome, its quite useless if the page is still loading. You cant call `driver.execute_script("window.stop();")` it wont work in chrome, but ff works perfectly fine.

Comment: What's the difference between using eager vs getting driver.page_source after the timeout exception ?

Comment: This answer need to be updated to selenium 4.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the selenium [docs V4.0](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/#none) it now seems to be like this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.page_load_strategy = 'none'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

@undetected Selenium answer works well but for the chrome, part its not working use the below answer for chrome

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
capa = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capa["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
browser= webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capa,executable_path='PATH',options=options)
```