# Python Selenium Explict wait doen not raise TimeoutException

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
def get_score(url):
    browser.get(url)
    elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='shopdsr-score-con']")))
    description_score = float(elements[0].text)
    service_score = float(elements[1].text)
    logistics_score = float(elements[2].text)
```

About is my code. Sometimes this may get stuck for quite long time and I expect there should be `TimeOutException` if it get stuck for 30 seconds because I have this code `wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30)`
But this never happens, the program just wait there...What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, you have set `WebDriverWait(browser, 30)` so effectively your code will be looking like :

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
def get_score(url):
    browser.get(url)
    elements = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='shopdsr-score-con']")))
    description_score = float(elements[0].text)
    service_score = float(elements[1].text)
    logistics_score = float(elements[2].text)
```

Logically, there is no error in your code block but the `the program just wait there` because when you invoke **`get(url)`** the web client i.e. **`PhantomJS Browser`** doesn't returns back **`document.readyState = "complete"`** so early. The **`JavaScript`** and the **`AJAX Calls`** still keeps loading. Hence **`Page Loading`** gets elongated.

Once the **`document.readyState = "complete"`** is returned by the web client i.e. **`PhantomJS Browser`** then only **`Selenium`** executes the next line of code:

```
elements = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='shopdsr-score-con']")))
```

Hence the program just wait there for some more time.

### Update :

As per your comment you need to look at the options of **`pageLoadStrategy`** either setting **`pageLoadStrategy`** to **`eager`** or **`none`** as per this QA [**`Don't wait for a page to load using Selenium in Python`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46322165/dont-wait-for-a-page-to-load-using-selenium-in-python/46339092#46339092)

Comment: Updated my Answer. Please mark the Answer as Accepted by clicking on the tick mark beside my Answer just below the VoteDown arrow so the tick mark turns green.

Answer (score 0):

use try,except

```
   from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

   timeout=30

   try:
       element_present1 = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username']"))
       WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present1)
   except TimeoutException:
       print "Timed out waiting for login page to load"
```