# How not to wait for the page to load when you click a button that redirects you to a page? java

Tags: java, selenium

I am doing a test of scenarios like this:

1. access protected link (driver.get(link))
2. redirect to login page
3. write username/pass and press login button
4. redirect to initial page

The problem is that after login the "initial page" is taking too much to load.
I only want to make a simple check on the page (1/2 elements) but it takes to long and I am losing time doing this.

So does anybody know a way to get around waiting for the page to load? (the elements I want are loaded fast +plus I wait for them after I get the context of the page)

I thought about taking the link from the button and do `driver.navigate.to(link_button)` but I want to avoid this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do to not wait for the whole page to load is to:

- specify ["eager" or "none" page load strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46339092/771848) (`normal` is default)

  > `normal`: This stategy causes Selenium to wait for the full page loading (html content and subresources downloaded and parsed).
  >
  > `eager`: This stategy causes Selenium to wait for the DOMContentLoaded event (html content downloaded and parsed only).
  >
  > `none`: This strategy causes Selenium to return immediately after the initial page content is fully received (html content downloaded).
- use `WebDriverWait` to wait for the element you need to check in this specific test scenario

And/or you can re-structure your tests and avoid navigating to the page when not logged in - e.g. going to login first to login -> navigate to the desired page.