# "Only local connections are allowed. Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver"

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I am using Chrome version 80, ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106 for automation testing.When executing the script it will gives following Error. How can I fix it(Changed the chrome driver versions. But no luck)

POM file dependency set up as selenium-chrome-driver version -3.141.59

```
    Starting ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609230cf9b635cd784cfb1bf81bb53a-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#882}) on port 5456
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Feb 27, 2020 11:50:29 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
[1582827630.873][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1582827630.975][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1582827631.077][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1582827631.180][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1582827631.280][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1582827631.382][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1582827631.483][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1582827631.585][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
```

Comment: it's a bug in Chromedriver 80.  Use 79 instead.  See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114639/timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-0-100-log-messages-using-chromedriver

Comment: Looks like a version issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114639/timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-0-100-log-messages-using-chromedriver