# Getting [1586297427.353][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100 ever since my Chrome browser updated to 81.0.4044.92

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

This issue has been existing for a while now with Selenium, I had a similar issue with chrome browser version 80.0.3987.163. After switching between a lot of chromedrivers I finally found version 79.0.3945.36 which tackled the issue. I barely found this a couple of days ago and now its back again when my browser auto-update to version 81.0.4044.92 because chromedriver 79.0.3945.36 probably got deprecated and doesn't support browser version of 81 and above. I read some comments on a another similar question that asked to try out chromedriver version 81.0.4044.20 and 81.0.4044.69. None of these version solve the issue and I keep getting the timeout message frequently while running my selenium tests. Please help this is frustrating, anybody got any workarounds I could implement?

Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114639/timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-0-100-log-messages-using-chromedriver

Comment: The solutions mentioned in the above url do not work for Chrome Browser Version 81 and above. Chromedriver 79.0.3945.36 tackled this issue for Chrome Browser Version 80. There was a update recently which updated browser version to 81.x.x.x and Chromedriver 79.0.3945.36 got deprecated, so need a similar solution for version 81 and above. Checking here to see if anyone was able to find one or is there a workaround for this.