# Timed out receiving message from renderer in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation, browser-automation

Hi I am facing following error while executing my UI test through selenium webdriver in chrome.

ChromeDriver: 81.0.4044.69.

[1586841277.704][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100

Can anybody help me to fix this?

Comment: Dup of a Q 1-2 months ago, but I don't have the SO skills to find it. It's a bug in current ChromeDriver, won't be fixed until the next version.

Comment: Correction: Actually it was a bug in ChromeDriver 80, was supposed to be *fixed* in 81. Sorry to hear, from your post, that apparently it's *not* fixed in 81.

Comment: Ok lets hope soon we find this bug fixed in next version and big thanks for your response.

Comment: Actually it might get fixed in 82: See the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114639.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that it is a recommended practice or not but after search on google i found this following temporary solution for this.

Set the browser property for chrome:

```
System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_SILENT_OUTPUT_PROPERTY, "true");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", DriverFactory.getChromeDriverExePath());

driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

for reference : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8GuQViFD3Y

Hope this will solve this problem for many of you.