# Selenium automation Page Loading is very Slow

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pageloadstrategy

I am using chromedriver for selenium automation.But webpage loading is very slow compared to manual testing.Kindly help

Getting error:

```
[1596549682.992][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000
```

Code trials:

```
ChromeOptions option=new ChromeOptions();
option.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NORMAL);
option.addArguments("--disable-features=NetworkService");
option.addArguments("--dns-prefetch-disable");
option.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
option.setProxy(null);
driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
```

Chrome version:84
Chrome driver Version:84
Selenium version:Tried 3.141.59 and 3.5.2

Comment: Why do you need `--disable-features=NetworkService`, `--dns-prefetch-disable` and `--disable-extensions`? What is your usecase?

Comment: i tried this because it was given as solution which is not working.My issue is when running the testcase sometimes pages are getting loaded fastt,but sometimes its taking too much time and giving timout exception.Should i add anything to option.I tried pageloadtimeout and implicit wait which is also not working.

Answer (score 2):

[Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) by default implements [`pageLoadStrategy`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/constant-values.html#org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType.PAGE_LOAD_STRATEGY) as **NORMAL**. So explicitly setting the same won't make any difference.

However, to avoid waiting for the slowly loading webpage you can set the capability [`java.lang.String PAGE_LOAD_STRATEGY`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/CapabilityType.html#PAGE_LOAD_STRATEGY) as **`none`** as follows:

```
ChromeOptions option=new ChromeOptions();
option.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);
driver = new ChromeDriver(option);
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Page load strategy for Chrome driver (Updated till Selenium v3.12.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43734797/page-load-strategy-for-chrome-driver-updated-till-selenium-v3-12-0/43737358#43737358)
- [How to make Selenium not wait till full page load, which has a slow script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770796/how-to-make-selenium-not-wait-till-full-page-load-which-has-a-slow-script/44771628#44771628)
- [Don't wait for a page to load using Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46322165/dont-wait-for-a-page-to-load-using-selenium-in-python/46339092#46339092)

---

### Timed out receiving message from renderer

To address this error you need to update [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) and [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) versions accordingly following the discussion in [Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100 log messages using ChromeDriver and Chrome v80 through Selenium Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114639/timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-0-100-log-messages-using-chromedriver)