# Undefined class constant 'pageLoadStrategy' {"exception":"[object] error during execution with Selenium PHP and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pageloadstrategy

i'm building web test code but i have error when first start

there seems to be something wrong at the beginning of code, but can't catche because don't know

```
 -error
 local.ERROR: Undefined class constant 'pageLoadStrategy' {"exception":"[object] 
(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Undefined class constant 
'pageLoadStrategy' at /var/www/app/Service/SeleniumSet/Set.php:38)

 -code
 $host = env('SELENIUM_HOST'); // this is the default
 $capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
 $capabilities->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);
 $capabilities->setCapability(ChromeOptions::pageLoadStrategy, 'nomal');
 $this->driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities, 7000);
 $this->driver->executeScript("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'plugins', {get: function() {return[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];},});");
    return $this->driver;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `nomal` the *`pageLoadStrategy`* should have been **`normal`**, effectively:

```
$capabilities->setCapability(ChromeOptions::pageLoadStrategy, 'normal');
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to make Selenium not wait till full page load, which has a slow script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770796/how-to-make-selenium-not-wait-till-full-page-load-which-has-a-slow-script/44771628#44771628)
- [Don't wait for a page to load using Selenium in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46322165/dont-wait-for-a-page-to-load-using-selenium-in-python/46339092#46339092)