# selenium - driver.get() without waiting (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, url, driver

I **don't** need the function driver.get() to wait until the page load, when I searched for a solution in Google I couldn't find anything in **Python**.

driver.get("https://kahoot.it/")

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the attribute "pageLoadStrategy".
Try to use this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46339092/13764201

Note that you either set the "pageLoadStrategy" to **eager** or use a manual wait to ensure that the page is interactive when you start using selenium features.