# Selenium unable to stop page loading

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pageload, pageloadstrategy

I do not face this problem with other websites but on this specific website:

**1-** I want to get my internet speed while using speedtest website by Selenium but the page cant stop loading. Because of that, I think that reason that I can't get the website elements.

**2-** Moreover, any line after self.driver.get can't be excited only if I stop the code.

[image]

Code trials:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class InternetSpeedTwitterBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def get_internet_speed(self):
        self.driver.get("https://www.speedtest.net/")
        print("go")
        self.driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "start-text").click()  # click on go 

browser = InternetSpeedTwitterBot()
browser.get_internet_speed()
```

I tried this method that I find it on more than one website but it did not help me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class InternetSpeedTwitterBot:
    def __init__(self):
        capa = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
        capa["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capa)
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20)

    def get_internet_speed(self):
        self.driver.get("https://www.speedtest.net/")
        self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "start-text")))
        self.driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
        print("go")
        self.driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "start-text").click()  # click on go

browser = InternetSpeedTwitterBot()
browser.get_internet_speed()
```

I don't understand anything but I just try it and it shows me an error:

```
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capa)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'desired_capabilities'
```

Comment: How long did you wait?  As I recall, speedtest takes a minute or two to run its test and show the results.

Comment: No, it doesn't even press go button or print("go"). anything after self.driver.get can't be excited only if I stop the code, that thing does not happen on other websites. it just keeps loading.

Comment: and if I stop code it shows me an error because find_element method doesn't find the anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [**`page_load_strategy`**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.html#selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.Options.page_load_strategy)

[page_load_strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44771628/7429447) is now an attribute. So you need to configure [*page_load_strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46339092/7429447) as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.page_load_strategy = 'none'
```

---

### Solution

With those minor few tweaks your working code will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class InternetSpeedTwitterBot:
    def __init__(self):
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument("start-maximized")
        options.page_load_strategy = 'none'
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20)

    def get_internet_speed(self):
        self.driver.get("https://www.speedtest.net/")
        self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
        self.driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
        self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.start-text").click()

browser = InternetSpeedTwitterBot()
browser.get_internet_speed()
```

Comment: Yes that is, thank you the code is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I try this codes above and find page loading is normally, so maybe it is you internet connection problem
you can view the document of pageloadstrategy
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/#pageloadstrategy

if you don't want to load image, you should set `edge_options.page_load_strategy = 'none'` like the document said.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver import EdgeOptions
import time
class InternetSpeedTwitterBot:
    def __init__(self):
        driverpath = r"C:\Users\10696\Desktop\access\6\msedgedriver.exe"
        service=Service(executable_path=driverpath)
        edge_options = EdgeOptions()
        edge_options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'
        self.driver = webdriver.Edge(options=edge_options, service = service)

    def get_internet_speed(self):
        self.driver.get("https://www.speedtest.net/")
        print("go")
        time.sleep(600)
        self.driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "test-mode-multi").click()  # click on go 

browser = InternetSpeedTwitterBot()
browser.get_internet_speed()
```

Comment: Yes, I tried it and it solved my problem, but the difference was in set page_load_strategy none not normal, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, now I can find the elemen even if the page is stuck at loading by using Options and page_load_strategy and waiting until the driver can find the button by WebDriverWait and expected_conditions.

**solution:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class InternetSpeedTwitterBot:
    def __init__(self):
        options = Options()
        options.add_experimental_option("detach", True) # for not close chrome
        options.page_load_strategy = "none" # for search element even if page stuck at loading
        
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    def get_internet_speed(self):
        self.driver.get("https://www.speedtest.net/")
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "start-text"))).click() # wait maximum 10 seconds for an element than click on go

browser = InternetSpeedTwitterBot()
browser.get_internet_speed()
```

basically the solution by using Options and page_load_strategy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).