# Selenium PhantomJS webdriver get partial screenshot

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, screenshot

This code save full web page, but I need to save just first view that user see(without scrolling down). Is it possible?

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
browser.set_page_load_timeout(60)
browser.get(url)
browser.save_screenshot(png_path)
```

**Update:**

Here is example of `save_screenshot` of `https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3223`, but I'm looking just for first view that user can see when he loads the page.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit what you mean by `need to save just first view`?

Answer (score 0):

To save the first `view` that user see, you have to tweak the configuration of **`pageLoadStrategy`** through **`DesiredCapabilities`** which is by default set as **`normal`** to **none** as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities().PHANTOMJS.copy()
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=caps, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\bin\phantomjs.exe')
browser.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
browser.set_page_load_timeout(60)
browser.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin")
browser.save_screenshot('./Screenshots/filename.png')
```

You can find a detailed discussion about [**`pageLoadStrategy`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770796/how-to-make-selenium-not-wait-till-full-page-load-which-has-a-slow-script/44771628#44771628) here.

Comment: Seems this don't work, for example I have tried `https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3223` and it saved screenshot of full html page.

Comment: @mrgloom But your question was about the first view **not full view** I suppose. So my solution was `Selenium` based.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'first view', but in my terminology first view is upper part of full page.

Comment: @mrgloom So what was the issue with your own code which looks perfect? Can you share the URL as well?

Comment: The problem is that is saves full html page, but I need only upper part of it and I obviously can't load full page and then crop upper part for performace reasons. Test url: `https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3223`

Comment: @mrgloom Can you narrow down to your exact requirement if you are looking for a snapshot of any particular WebElement. Probably I have a solution for you.

Comment: It should work for any web page, I don't know web element beforehand.