# How to interact with an element before it is rendered within the HTML DOM through Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, pageloadstrategy

Is it possible request an URL and check for the elements before the page renders?
I'm using Python + Selenium.

Comment: Why do you want to check for elements before the page renders? What is your goal? Do you have some `code trials` for us to work off of?

Comment: I'm checking an available date in the calendar to book an appointment. There's no reason to load the entire page, just ckeck for the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A one word answer to your question will be **Yes**.

### Explanation

Generally each *WebElement* on a webpage have 3 (three) distinct states as follows:

- **`presence`**: Element is present on the DOM of a page.
- **`visibility`**: Element is present on the DOM of a page and visible.
- **`interactable`(i.e. `clickable`)**:  Element is visible and enabled such that you can click it.

When Selenium loads a webpage/url by default it follows a default configuration of `pageLoadStrategy` set to **`normal`**. You can opt not to wait for the complete page load. So to avoid waiting for the full webpage to load you can configure the `pageLoadStrategy`. `pageLoadStrategy` supports 3 different values as follows:

1. **`normal`** (complete page load)
2. **`eager`** (interactive)
3. **`none`**

Here is a sample code block to configure the **`pageLoadStrategy`** :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX.copy()
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(desired_capabilities=caps, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("http://google.com")
```

You can find a detailed discussion in [How to make Selenium not wait till full page load, which has a slow script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770796/how-to-make-selenium-not-wait-till-full-page-load-which-has-a-slow-script/44771628#44771628)