# webscraping returns not full info

Tags: python, web-scraping, telegram

learning webscraping at the moment and decided to scrap telegram's web version
so
i choosed one of the chats (favorite one with yourself) and sent few voices there.
My task is - i want to exract all voices lenght
when i inspect page there is a div container `<div class="audio-time">0:00</div>`

```
telegramURL = 'https://web.telegram.org/k/#@myname'

audiolength = requests.get(telegramURL)

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(audiolength.text, 'lxml')

audio2 = soup.find_all('div', class_=re.compile('audio-time'))[0]

print(audio2)
```

all i get is an empty massive []

maybe i should use different parser? or url im using is wroing as it is not an official API or anything else

also - while inspecting the page in the browser i can see this div container but when i get it with beauitful soup it seems like not full.

```
<p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="https://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience and security.</p>
  <![endif]--><div class="whole" id="auth-pages" style="display:none"><div class="scrollable scrollable-y"><div class="tabs-container auth-pages__container" data-animation="tabs"><div class="tabs-tab page-signImport"><div class="container center-align"></div></div><div class="tabs-tab page-sign"><div class="container"><div class="auth-image"><svg class="sign-logo" height="160" viewbox="0 0 160 160" width="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><use href="#logo"></use></svg></div></div></div><div class="tabs-tab page-signQR"><div class="container center-align"><div class="auth-image"></div></div></div><div class="tabs-tab page-authCode"><div class="container center-align"><div class="auth-image"></div><div class="phone-wrapper"><h4 class="phone"></h4><span class="phone-edit tgico-edit"></span></div><p class="subtitle sent-type"></p><div class="input-wrapper"></div></div></div><div class="tabs-tab page-password"></div><div class="tabs-tab page-signUp"></div></div></div></div><div class="whole page-chats" id="page-chats" style="display:none"><svg style="position:absolute;top:-10000px;left:-10000px"><defs id="svg-defs"><path d="M1.00002881,1.03679295e-14 L7,0 L7,17 C6.8069969,14.1607017 6.12380234,11.2332513 4.95041634,8.21764872 C4.04604748,5.89342034 2.50413132,3.73337411 0.324667862,1.73751004 L0.324652538,1.73752677 C-0.0826597201,1.36452676 -0.110475289,0.731958677 0.262524727,0.324646419 C0.451952959,0.117792698 0.719544377,1.0985861e-14 1.00002881,1.04360964e-14 Z" id="message-tail"></path><path d="M80,0 C124.18278,0 160,35.81722 160,80 C160,124.18278 124.18278,160 80,160 C35.81722,160 0,124.18278 0,80 C0,35.81722 35.81722,0 80,0 Z M114.262551,46.4516129 L114.123923,46.4516129 C111.089589,46.5056249 106.482806,48.0771432 85.1289541,56.93769 L81.4133571,58.4849956 C72.8664779,62.0684477 57.2607933,68.7965125 34.5963033,78.66919 C30.6591745,80.2345564 28.5967328,81.765936 28.4089783,83.2633288 C28.0626453,86.0254269 31.8703852,86.959903 36.7890378,88.5302703 L38.2642674,89.0045258 C42.3926354,90.314406 47.5534685,91.7248852 50.3250916,91.7847532 C52.9151948,91.8407003 55.7944784,90.8162976 58.9629426,88.7115451 L70.5121776,80.9327422 C85.6657026,70.7535853 93.6285785,65.5352892 94.4008055,65.277854 L94.6777873,65.216416 C95.1594319,65.1213105 95.7366278,65.0717596 96.1481181,65.4374337 C96.6344248,65.8695939 96.5866185,66.6880224 96.5351057,66.9075859 C96.127514,68.6448691 75.2839361,87.6143392 73.6629144,89.2417998 L73.312196,89.6016896 C68.7645143,94.2254793 63.9030972,97.1721503 71.5637945,102.355193 L73.3593638,103.544598 C79.0660342,107.334968 82.9483395,110.083813 88.8107882,113.958377 L90.3875424,114.996094 C95.0654739,118.061953 98.7330313,121.697601 103.562866,121.253237 C105.740839,121.052855 107.989107,119.042224 109.175465,113.09692 L109.246762,112.727987 C112.002037,98.0012935 117.417883,66.09303 118.669527,52.9443975 C118.779187,51.7924073 118.641237,50.318088 118.530455,49.6708963 L118.474159,49.3781963 C118.341081,48.7651315 118.067967,48.0040758 117.346762,47.4189793 C116.412565,46.6610871 115.002114,46.4638844 114.262551,46.4516129 Z" fill-rule="evenodd" id="logo"></path><path d="M4.47,5.33v13.6c0,4.97,4.03,9,9,9h458.16" id="poll-line"></path><path d="M 4.7071 12.2929 l 5 5 c 0.3905 0.3905 1.0237 0.3905 1.4142 0 l 11 -11" fill="none" id="check"></path><path clip-rule="evenodd" d="m14.378741 1.509638 1.818245 1.818557c.365651.365716.861601.571194 1.378741.571259l2.574273.000312c1.01361.000117 1.846494.773578 1.940861 1.762436l.008905.187798-.000312 2.5727c-.000065.517322.205439 1.013454.571259 1.379222l1.819649 1.819337c.714441.713427.759174 1.843179.134563 2.609139l-.134797.148109-1.819181 1.8182502c-.365963.3657823-.571558.8620196-.571493 1.3794456l.000312 2.5737972c.000559 1.0136048-.772668 1.846676-1.7615 1.9412861l-.188266.0084786-2.573792-.0003107c-.517426-.0000624-1.013675.2055248-1.379456.5714956l-1.818245 1.8191823c-.71331.7145515-1.843049.7594886-2.609113.1349998l-.148135-.1347645-1.8193435-1.8196542c-.3657628-.3658252-.8618987-.5713214-1.3792103-.571259l-2.5727052.0003107c-1.0136048.0001222-1.846676-.7731321-1.9412861-1.761968l-.0089492-.1877967-.0003107-2.5742678c-.0000624-.5171478-.2055495-1.0130926-.571259-1.3787397l-1.8185622-1.8182515c-.7139886-.713869-.758706-1.843647-.1340846-2.609607l.1338493-.148109 1.8190328-1.81935c.3655665-.365625.5709613-.861471.5710237-1.378494l.0003107-2.573181c.0006006-1.076777.8734635-1.949636 1.9502353-1.950234l2.5731758-.000312c.5170321-.000065 1.0128768-.205452 1.3785044-.571025l1.8193448-1.819038c.761592-.761449 1.996254-.761345 2.757716.000247zm3.195309 8.047806c-.426556-.34125-1.032655-.306293-1.417455.060333l-.099151.108173-4.448444 5.55815-1.7460313-1.74707-.1104961-.096564c-.4229264-.32188-1.0291801-.289692-1.4154413.096564-.3862612.386269-.4184492.992511-.0965653 1.41544l.0965653.1105 2.5999987 2.5999987.109876.0961467c.419874.320359 1.015131.2873897 1.397071-.0773773l.098579-.107692 5.2-6.4999961.083772-.120484c.273208-.455884.174278-1.054885-.252278-1.396122z" fill-rule="evenodd" id="verified-icon-background"></path><path d="M8 8H18V18H8V8Z" id="verified-icon-check"></path><symbol id="message-tail-filled" viewbox="0 0 11 20"><g fill="inherit" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(9 -14)"><path d="M-6 16h6v17c-.193-2.84-.876-5.767-2.05-8.782-.904-2.325-2.446-4.485-4.625-6.48A1 1 0 01-6 16z" fill="inherit" id="corner-fill" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 49)"></path></g></symbol><lineargradient id="g" x1="-300%" x2="-200%" y1="0" y2="0"><stop offset="-10%" stop-opacity=".1"></stop><stop offset="30%" stop-opacity=".07"></stop><stop offset="70%" stop-opacity=".07"></stop><stop offset="110%" stop-opacity=".1"></stop><animate attributename="x1" dur="3s" from="-300%" repeatcount="indefinite" to="1200%"></animate><animate attributename="x2" dur="3s" from="-200%" repeatcount="indefinite" to="1300%"></animate></lineargradient></defs></svg><div class="tabs-container" data-animation="navigation" id="main-columns"><div class="tabs-tab chatlist-container sidebar sidebar-left main-column" id="column-left"><div class="sidebar-slider tabs-container"><div class="tabs-tab sidebar-slider-item item-main"><div class="sidebar-header"><div class="sidebar-header__btn-container"><div class="animated-menu-icon"></div><div class="btn-icon sidebar-back-button"></div></div></div><div class="sidebar-content transition zoom-fade"><div class="transition-item active" id="chatlist-container"><div class="folders-tabs-scrollable menu-horizontal-scrollable hide"><nav class="menu-horizontal-div" id="folders-tabs"></nav></div><div class="tabs-container" id="folders-container"></div></div><div class="transition-item sidebar-search" id="search-container"></div></div></div></div></div><div class="tabs-tab main-column" id="column-center"></div><div class="tabs-tab sidebar sidebar-right main-column" id="column-right"><div class="sidebar-content sidebar-slider tabs-container"></div></div></div><div class="emoji-dropdown" id="emoji-dropdown" style="display:none"><div class="emoji-container"><div class="tabs-container"><div class="tabs-tab emoji-padding"><div class="menu-wrapper"><nav class="menu-horizontal-div no-stripe justify-start"></nav></div><div class="emoticons-content" id="content-emoji"></div></div><div class="tabs-tab stickers-padding"><div class="menu-wrapper"><nav class="menu-horizontal-div no-stripe justify-start"></nav></div><div class="emoticons-content" id="content-stickers"></div></div><div class="tabs-tab gifs-padding"><div class="emoticons-content" id="content-gifs"><div class="gifs-masonry"></div></div></div></div></div><div class="emoji-tabs menu-horizontal-div no-stripe"><button class="menu-horizontal-div-item emoji-tabs-search justify-self-start btn-icon tgico-search" data-tab="-1"></button> <button class="menu-horizontal-div-item emoji-tabs-emoji btn-icon tgico-smile" data-tab="0"></button> <button class="menu-horizontal-div-item emoji-tabs-stickers btn-icon tgico-stickers_face" data-tab="1"></button> <button class="menu-horizontal-div-item emoji-tabs-gifs btn-icon tgico-gifs" data-tab="2"></button> <button class="menu-horizontal-div-item emoji-tabs-delete justify-self-end btn-icon tgico-deleteleft" data-tab="-1"></button></div></div></div></body></html>
```

i get this when i exract full page of a chat
but when i do the same in the browser i see this div i needed

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the parser, it's beautiful soup itself. Last time I've used it can only do static scraping which means it only returns the html to traverse the DOM and if it had any scripts in it wouldn't load.

Static scraping ignores JavaScript.

You have to switch to *Selenium* with a chrome webdriver. It has similar functionality as BeautifulSoup with a [pageLoadStrategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770796/how-to-make-selenium-not-wait-till-full-page-load-which-has-a-slow-script/44771628#44771628) in order to load the website as you'd expect.

Comment: *The problem is not the parser, it's beautiful soup itself* - That is not correct `BeautifulSoup` does not necessarily have anything to do with this, but the behaviour you outline is rather to be attributed to the `requests` module.